# How to rename a file while storing it to a GCS bucket

Tags: python-2.7, amazon-s3, google-cloud-platform, cloud

I am reading a file from one of directory.post validations I need  to upload a file with appending timestamp to it.

How do I rename the file while uploading it to a GCS bucket?

I am using the Google Storage client. I see that for S3 the boto client has a method where we can pass a `upload_name=` parameter but I don't see a similar one in GCS.

Answer (score 4):

In case if you want to rename an existing file in the bucket.

```
def rename_blob(bucket_name, blob_name, new_blob_name):
    """
    Function for renaming file in a bucket buckets.

    inputs
    -----
    bucket_name: name of bucket
    blob_name: str, name of file 
        ex. 'data/some_location/file_name'
    new_blob_name: str, name of file in new directory in target bucket 
        ex. 'data/destination/file_name'
    """
    storage_client = storage.Client.from_service_account_json('creds.json')

    bucket = storage_client.bucket(bucket_name)
    blob = bucket.blob(blob_name)
    new_blob = bucket.rename_blob(blob, new_blob_name)
    return new_blob.public_url
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use **rename_blob** to achieve the same result.

```
from google.cloud import storage

storage_client = storage.Client() 
bucket = storage_client.get_bucket("mybucket")
blob = bucket.blob("myfile")
blob.upload_from_filename("mynewfile")
bucket.rename_blob(blob, "mynewfile")
```

Another alternative is using the [rest API](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/objects/insert) where you can just pass the name parameter.